# Bootstrap TokenField dropdown Item Flickering on Select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using a bootstrap tokenfield with an autocomplete dropdown. However, when you hover over the dropdown, it is very evident that the text moves slightly. Is there any way to fix this, so that the text does not move at all on hover?

Please run code to see the problem. The dropdown is in the modal. Thanks so much for the help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<style>
      .ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-autocomplete.ui-front {
        z-index: 1051; // Or more
      }

      .token-input {
        width: 25vmin !important;
      }

      .tokenfield .token {
        height: 25px;
      }

      .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none !important;
        text-decoration: none;
        }

      .ui-menu-item {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 0.25rem 1.5rem;
          clear: both;
          font-weight: 400;
          color: #000000;
          text-align: inherit;
          white-space: nowrap;
          background-color: transparent;
          border: 0;
          border-radius: 0.5rem;
        }

        .ui-menu-item:hover, .ui-menu-item:focus {
          color: #ffffff;
          text-decoration: none;
          background-color: #eaeaf1;
        }

        .ui-menu-item:hover{
          color: #ffffff;
        }

        .ui-menu:hover  .ui-menu-item-wrapper, .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover{
            background: transparent;
            border: none;
        }
        .ui-menu {           border-radius: 3px !important;         }

        .form-control {
          height: inherit;
        }

      @media (max-width: 600px) {
        .ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-autocomplete.ui-front {
            width: auto !important; /* important is used because tokenfield api uses inline styling */
        }
      }
</style>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value=""/>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
</body>

<script>

          var sourceDataObj = ["test1", "test2", "3tests"];

            $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
                autocomplete: {
                    source: sourceDataObj,
                    delay: 100
            },
                showAutocompleteOnFocus: true,
                    minWidth: 466

            });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Few issues in your custom CSS fixed now.

1. You have some background transparent which is not needed.
2. `border:none !important` is not working.
3. `.ui-menu-item` no need to use custom CSS style for this as the styles provided by token fields are responsive.

**Edit:** I have also added a max height and overflow-y as you *wanted* if your dropdown items are more then 10+ you can adjust the height as you wish too.

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sourceDataObj = ["test1", "test2", "3tests","test1", "test2", "3tests","test1", "test2", "3tests","test1", "test2", "3tests","test1", "test2", "3tests","test1", "test2", "3tests","test1", "test2", "3tests","test1", "test2", "3tests","test1", "test2", "3tests","test1", "test2", "3tests","test1", "test2", "3tests","test1", "test2", "3tests",];
  $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
    autocomplete: {
      source: sourceDataObj,
      delay: 100
    },
    showAutocompleteOnFocus: true,
    minWidth: 466

  });

});
```

```css
.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-autocomplete.ui-front {
  z-index: 1051; // Or more
}
 
 #ui-id-1 {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 300px;
 }

.token-input {
  width: 25vmin !important;
}

.tokenfield .token {
  height: 25px;
}

.ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}

.ui-menu {
  border-radius: 3px !important;
}

.form-control {
  height: inherit;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-autocomplete.ui-front {
    width: auto !important;
    /* important is used because tokenfield api uses inline styling */
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tokenfield/0.12.0/bootstrap-tokenfield.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
  <style>

  </style>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I don't know who downvoted... One question, is it possible to change the background color on hover, as I did in my original post, and remove the black rectangle that appears on hover with the code you provided? Thanks!!!

Comment: @bobe Thanks - Glad to hear. Let me check the black rectangle as well. I have not see that at all. Do not forget to accept the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as the solution - Thank i will update my asnwer with if possible to change the color.

Comment: just accepted the answer. Wondering if you also know how to make the autocomplete scroll if it has hypothetically 100+ elements, as currently it goes off the screen... Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: @bobe Thanks very much. I would suggest using `overflow: scroll` CSS on the list item to make it scroll-able if items are more.

Comment: @bobe I have edited my answer to add an overflow and scroll options are 10+ elements or more then that. You can set the `height` as you wish too.

Comment: do you know how to adjust the height based on the number of elements, for example if there is 1 element, I want the height to just contain that element instead of having tons of whitespace on bottom..., however if there is 1000, I want it to have the max fixed height and overflow scroll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217674/discussion-between-bob-e-and-alwayshelping).

Comment: @bobe Okay i get you - to do this dynamically. you have your jQuery for this. Something like if `.length is > 1` then do css of overflow else do not do the anything. It would be ideal if you post an other question for this one :)